# if iOS enterprise distribution certificate is expired, my app will can not open?

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

I have a app that use enterprise distribution certificate archive, but the enterprise distribution certificate will expired, if it expired, The app installed on the user's iPhone will not open？

Comment: The IPA file will run in the device , you could not able to archive new IPA file with expired in house certificate, the Xcode show you an error

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to confirm that I said is the enterprise certificate rather than in the apple store release certificate, if it does not affect the installed users, no better than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some twists and turns, I know the answer.My app can not open When the enterprise distribution certificate had expired, but not immediately, it was over a few hours.I can only use the new certificate to archive a new ipa.